# SQLAlchemy / Alembic raw SQL for adding index

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'd like to use the following raw SQL to create an index in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_action_date ON events_map ((action ->> 'action'), date, map_id);
```

I tried to put this line into the model class's `__table_args__` part, but I couldn't. Then I simply solved it by using raw SQL in Alembic migration.

```
conn = op.get_bind()
conn.execute(text("CREATE INDEX ..."))
```

and just using a dummy index in `__table_args__` like:

```
Index('ix_action_date')
```

My only problem is that Alembic doesn't accept the dummy index with the same name, and every time I run a `revision --autogenerate`, it tells me the following:

```
SAWarning: Skipped unsupported reflection of expression-based index ix_action_date
  % idx_name)
```

and then it adds the autogenerated index to the migration file:

```
op.create_index('ix_action_date', 'events_map', [], unique=False)
```

My question is:

1. How can I write raw SQL into a `__table_args__` Index?
2. How can I really make my dummy index concept work ? I mean an index which is only compared by name?

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about "I tried to put this line into the model class's `__table_args__` part, but I couldn't"? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM. Each model is specified in a class. The __table_args__ variable on that class specifies custom properties for the table, like indexes. I'd like to declare my index in table_args.

Comment: Meant more like edit your question to include your declarative definition with the failed attempt and how it fails. If you're creating the index in your migration manually using raw SQL, you don't necessarily even need the `Index` in your table args, not to mention a "dummy" one.

Comment: You are right, it seems that if I remove the Index from table args, it works, I just need to live with: `Skipped unsupported reflection of expression-based index` for every `--autogenerate`.

Comment: Still in relation to the 1st comment, SQLA supports expressions in indexes, at least for Postgresql dialect, so creating an `Index` definition for the json(b) column expression and the rest should've been feasible.

Comment: Yes, I'm still interested in finding this out. My failed attempts were quick and meaningless, if someone can share the information it'd be a valueable information.

Comment: @hyperknot you can live without it by ignoring the warnings before:
`warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', r"^Skipped unsupported reflection of expression-based index [A-Za-z_]+$", SAWarning)`
`warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', r"autogenerate skipping functional index [A-Za-z_]+; not supported by SQLAlchemy reflection$", UserWarning)`

Answer (score 4):

> How can I write raw SQL into a `__table_args__` Index?

To specify formula indexes, you have to provide a text element for the expression

example:

```
class EventsMap(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events_map'
    __table_args__ = (Index('ix_action_date', text("(action->>'action'), date, map_id")),)
    map_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime)
    action = Column(JSONB)
```

> How can I really make my dummy index concept work ? I mean an index which is only compared by name?

It seems unnecessary to make your dummy index concept work. Either specify the full index expression in the `__table_args__` as I've shown above, or omit it completely from the model & delegate index creation as a database migration handled by sqlalchemy.